# Jenkin Pipeline does not execute the next stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkinfile like this

> > ```
> > node any {
> >   def global variables.
> >    stage {
> >       //build job 1
> >        build job 'job1'       
> >       } 
> >     stage{
> >       //build job 2 
> >       build job 'job2'
> >        }
> > ```

What's happening when i run this is , job 1 gets successfully built on jenkins, but anything written after the first 'build' statement doesn't get executed. I have tried moving the stages around the first always work but second doesn't as the control never reaches to second stage.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to be clear: this is scripted syntax, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried naming your stages ? As shown here : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals

```
node any {
  def global variables.
  stage('Build 1') {
   //build job 1
   build job: 'job1'       
  } 
  stage('Build 2') {
    //build job 2 
    build job: 'job2'
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the stages are named.